# SCSS styles imported to components in app.js are being applied to all components in app.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am using react-router and am importing styles and components into my app.js. The issue is that any styles that applied in say Login then are somehow also applied to Home, Item, and Bag. Looking at source in chrome it shows all of the css files being loaded whenever I go to any of the pages. I am using webpack and I think this might be the issue but I have no idea what in it is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

````
import '../../styles/styles.scss';
import '../../styles/generalStyle.scss';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';

import {
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import NotFound from './NotFound';

import Login from '../Login/Login';
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import Item from '../Item/Item';
import Bag from '../Bag/Bag';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/item/:name" component={Item} />
          <Route path="/bag" component={Bag} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ReactJS` the css is not `component` scope. The css is global scope. so if you add a css file in any component then it will apply to whole app.

If you want css to be component scope then you could use 'CSS Modules'

> This project supports CSS Modules alongside regular stylesheets using the [name].module.css file naming convention. CSS Modules allows the scoping of CSS by automatically creating a unique classname of the format [filename]_[classname]__[hash].

you could read more about this [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Comment: I am using scss files. Is there a similar solution for those?

Comment: refer to this URL. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You need **css modules** to **scope the styles** for a particular component. Because **css styles** are **global** in nature.

**Quick question**:

Are you using [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) in your webpack config? If so when you build the application via webpack, all the **styles in js** (**imported scss files**) are pulled in to **one single file** and injected into index.html page.

First you need to convert your **scss files** to **css modules** and do the below you get what you need.

This [link](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules) should help you in converting the scss files to css modules.

**Example**:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true, // this one make existing scss to css modules
    },
  },
```

Lets assume you have convert scss to css modules. Lets see an example.

Eg: **page1.scss**, **page2.scss** to **styles.css**

I would suggest to split styles according to your need. Lets see an example for your above code.

Eg: **vendor.css** (contains **bootstrap** and **general** styles) and **main.css** (contains **component styles**)

Example: **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

function recursiveIssuer(m) {
  if (m.issuer) {
    return recursiveIssuer(m.issuer);
  } else if (m.name) {
    return m.name;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/vendor'),
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main'),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          name: 'foo',
          test: (m, c, entry = 'vendor') =>
            m.constructor.name === 'CssModule' && recursiveIssuer(m) === entry,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
        main: {
          name: 'bar',
          test: (m, c, entry = 'main') =>
            m.constructor.name === 'CssModule' && recursiveIssuer(m) === entry,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Above file is an example taken directly from **mini-css-extract-plugin** plugin page.

**Explanation:**

Above config will create two files, one for **vendor.css** and one for **main.css**. Like this you can create `n` number of styles for your routes and use it accordingly.

Hope this help!